# How to fetch comments with Facebook Graph API from comments plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get all comments from my website.
I have found [this method in plugin FAQ](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1603507626630008):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/?fields=og_object{comments}
  &id=<YOUR_URL>
  &access_token=<YOUR_TOKEN>
```

But it neither corresponds to [API reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/url) (there's no field named `comments` in returned OpenGraph object), nor actually works. So I managed only to fetch amount of comments, but not actually their contents. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

The code referred to in the FAQ appears to be for v2.6 of the API, and so may be superceded.

I get comments from the Comments Plugin with the following.

First I get the Facebook Graph ID for the URL the Comments Plugin is operating within:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/?id=<<YOUR_URL>>
    &access_token=<<YOUR_TOKEN>>
```

This returns a response like this:

```
{
  "og_object": {
    "id": "<<OBJECT_ID>>",
    "description": "<<OPENGRAPH_DESCRIPTION>>",
    "title": "<<OPENGRAPH_TITLE>>",
    "type": "article",
    "updated_time": "2017-02-08T13:53:48+0000"
  },
  "share": {
    "comment_count": 0,
    "share_count": 0
  },
  "id": "<<YOUR_URL>>"
}
```

We then take that Open Graph Object ID and plug it into this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/<<OBJECT_ID>>/comments?summary=1
    &filter=stream
    &order=reverse_chronological
    &access_token=<<YOUR_TOKEN>>
```

You'll get an object with a data property which will be an array of comments.

### Testing for URL Provided by OP

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/
    id=http://pdffiller.com/6962253&access_token=[REDACTED]
```

Returned

```
{
  "og_object": {
    "id": "1195506680497732",
    "description": "Fill w9 fill out online 2014-2017  form irs instantly, download blank or editable online. Sign, fax and printable from PC, iPad, tablet or mobile. No software. Try Now!",
    "title": "2014-2017 Form IRS W-9 Fill Online, Printable, Fillable, Blank - PDFfiller",
    "type": "website",
    "updated_time": "2017-02-08T12:08:37+0000"
  },
  "share": {
    "comment_count": 0,
    "share_count": 24
  },
  "id": "http://pdffiller.com/6962253"
}
```

Note the `comment_count` is zero, hence why no comments are returned by the Graph API

Comment: It seems it doesn't work. `data` is an empty array, despite I have `"comment_count": 7,` field in `share`object

Comment: @AndriyMaletsky What is the URL of the page you are trying to get the comments for? My code works OK for me, but I am happy to test it in trying to see the comments you are looking for

Comment: @AndriyMaletsky, I have updated by answer with testing using your URL. There are no comments being returned because there are no comments to be returned

Comment: that's because you've missed trailing dash in the url. We have a heap of legacy code with multiple urls per page, with every url having some special meaning:)